# I can't replace my user's image with a new image with Axios React Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, post, axios

I am creating a corporate social network and I would like to create a button change the user's image, except that I have a problem when I send my image to me send invalid format while I put a correct format. At your disposal you have the code for my image button etc and you have my back side on which I make my call to update the user's image, and two screens with what the console returns to me.

Code button :

```
  const [file, setFile] = useState()

  function handleChange(event) {
    setFile(event.target.files[0])
  }
  
  function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    const url = 'http://localhost:4200/api/user/upload';
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', file);
    formData.append('fileName', file.name);
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
      },
    };
    axios.post(url, formData, config).then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
    });

  } 

return (
    <>
      <Topbar />
      <div className="profile">
        <div className="profileRight">
          <div className="profileRightTop">
            <div className="profileCover">
              {user && <img
                className="profileUserImg"
                src={user.picture}
                alt=""
              />}
            </div>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
              <p>Modifier img </p>
              <input type="file" onChange={handleChange} />
              <button type="submit">Upload</button>
            </form>
            <div className="profileInfo">
                {user && <h4 className="profileInfoName">{user.nom} {user.prenom}</h4>}
                {user && <span className="profileInfoDesc">{user.bio}</span>}
                <input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setUserBio(e.target.value) }}/>
                <button onClick={testbio} >modifier descirption</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="profileRightBottom">
            <Feed />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Code Backend :

```
const UserModel = require("../models/user.model");
const fs = require("fs");
const { promisify } = require("util");
const pipeline = promisify(require("stream").pipeline);
const { uploadErrors } = require("../utils/errors.utils");

module.exports.uploadProfil = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log({file :req.file, body : req.body});
    if (
      req.file.mimetype != "images/jpg" &&
      req.file.mimetype != "images/png" &&
      req.file.mimetype != "images/jpeg"
    )
      throw Error("invalid file");

    if (req.file.size > 500000) throw Error("max size");
  } catch (err) {
    const errors = uploadErrors(err);
    return res.status(201).json({ errors });
  }
  const fileName = req.body.name + ".jpg";

  await pipeline(
    req.file.stream,
    fs.createWriteStream(
      `${__dirname}/../images/profil/${fileName}`
    )
  );

  try {
    await UserModel.findByIdAndUpdate(
      req.body.userId,
      { $set : {picture: "./images/profil/" + fileName}},
      { new: true, upsert: true, setDefaultsOnInsert: true},
      (err, docs) => {
        if (!err) return res.send(docs);
        else return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
      }
    );
  } catch (err) {
    return res.status(500).send({ message: err });
  }
};
```

[image]

[image]